# What determines exactly when scheduled lambda invocation triggered by cloudwatch event happens?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-event-bridge

I have two lambda functions that are scheduled to run once every hour via an event. One of them is invoked every hour at five minutes before the hour and the other goes at two minutes after. What determines this? Is it just the time the lambda was deployed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Read the [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-create-rule-schedule.html#eb-rate-expressions)!

> **A *rate expression* starts when you create the scheduled event rule**, and then it runs on a defined schedule.

In order to run at an exact minute, use a [cron expression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-create-rule-schedule.html#eb-cron-expressions).